# C++11 move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

What would be the correct way to implement a move constructor considering the following class:

```
class C {
public:
    C();
    C(C&& c);
private:
    std::string string;
}
```

Of course, the idea is to avoid copying `string` or deallocating it twice.
Lets assume the basic example is just for clarity and I do need a move constructor.

I tried:

```
C::C(C&& c) {
    //move ctor
    string = std::move(c.string);
}
```

And

```
C::C(C&& c) : string(std::move(c.string)) {
    //move ctor
}
```

Both compile fine on gcc 4.8 and run fine. It *seems* option A is the correct behaviour, `string` gets copied instead of moved with option B.
Is this the correct implementation of a move constructor?

Comment: The correct implementation is just let the compiler generate it. `class C { std::string string; };`

Comment: This is of course a simple example. I do need a move constructor. What do I do with the string in this case? Ignore it?

Comment: @KennyTM VC11 Beta doesn't automatically generate default move constructors or move assignment operators.

Comment: The first one constructs `string`, then moves.  The second one is better.  Also: don't name variables the same as a type.  Option B _should_ be moving the string.

Comment: That is what I thought, however the second one is the one that creates 2 instances of string. gcc4.8 is still beta though...

Comment: @Fraser: (1) OP mentioned gcc 4.8, which does automatically generate move c'tors (even 4.7 does), and (2) that's VC11's bug.

Comment: @ssteinberg "2 instances of string"? A move constructor does not automatically decrement the number of instances of classes. I think you should show your testcase and the reason you think that something goes wrong.

Comment: @KennyTM I know gcc was mentioned, but it's probably not good advice at the moment to rely on compiler generated move constructors unless it's clear that *only* compliant compilers will be used.  (Also, I wouldn't call this a bug so much as missing functionality)

Comment: Debugger shows std::string gets copied instead of moved with option B, unlike A. I am asking as it didn't strike me as the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `std::string` itself has a move-ctor, the implicitly defined move-ctor for `C` will take care of the proper move operation. You may not define it yourself. However, if you have any other data member and specifically:

> **12.8 Copying and moving class objects**
>
> **12** An implicitly-declared copy/move constructor is an inline public
> member of its class. A defaulted copy- /move constructor for a class X
> is defined as deleted (8.4.3) if X has:
>
> — a variant member with a
> non-trivial corresponding constructor and X is a union-like class,
>
> — a
> non-static data member of class type M (or array thereof) that cannot
> be copied/moved because overload resolution (13.3), as applied to M’s
> corresponding constructor, results in an ambiguity or a function that
> is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted constructor, or
>
> — a
> direct or virtual base class B that cannot be copied/moved because
> overload resolution (13.3), as applied to B’s corresponding
> constructor, results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or
> inaccessible from the defaulted constructor, or
>
> — for the move
> constructor, a non-static data member or direct or virtual base class
> with a type that does not have a move constructor and is not trivially
> copyable.
>
> **13** A copy/move constructor for class X is trivial if it is
> neither user-provided nor deleted and if
>
> — class X has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
>
> — the
> constructor selected to copy/move each direct base class subobject is
> trivial, and
>
> — for each non-static data member of X that is of class
> type (or array thereof), the constructor selected to copy/move that
> member is trivial; otherwise the copy/move constructor is non-trivial.

you may want to implement your own move-ctor.

In case you need the move-ctor, prefer the initializer list syntax. Always! Otherwise, you may end up with a default construction per object not mentioned in the initializer list (which is what you're forced for member objects with non-default ctors only).

Answer (score 11):

Both your variants will move the string. The second variant should be preferred because it will not default construct an empty string just to move assign it afterwards.

Check your testcase and then your compiler's bugzilla list. You need to trace calls to both `string::operator=(string&&)` (1st case) *and* `string::string(string&&)` (2nd case) if you want to ensure for both cases that they move.

Comment: That is what I did. In second case no move operator/constructors are called.

Answer (score 3):

Both Constructors should work. So both are correct move constructors. The second one might be more efficient, since the first one default constructs `string` only to assign to it, while the second will simply move construct it and should therefore be more efficient. If the second one is less efficient I would suspect a compiler bug (remember that C++11 support is still not complete for current compilers) or a flawed test methology (how exactly do you test copy vs move and are you sure the move constructor not the assignment op is called in both cases?).

Of course whenever possibly you could simply let the compiler generate your constructor via `C(C&&) = default;`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to implement a move constructor here since you don't have to manually manage memory. Move constructors are only useful when you manually use dynamic arrays in your class.

You can still explicitly have the compiler create the default move constructor even though it should have already been done even if you don't request it:

```
C(C&& c) = default;
```

Comment: I find *mocha* constructors useful.