# How to move a non-copyable element from std::set to std::map using extract?

Tags: c++, c++17, move-semantics, stdmap, stdset

Consider the following:

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <map>

struct MyClass
{
    MyClass(int i);
    MyClass(MyClass const&) = delete;
    ~MyClass();

    bool operator<(const MyClass& r) const { return v < r.v; }
    int v;
};

void map_set_move_test()
{
    std::set<MyClass> s1, s2;
    std::map<int, MyClass> m1;

    s1.emplace(123);

    s2.insert(std::move(s1.extract(s1.begin())));

    // This fails
    m1.insert(std::move(std::make_pair(1, std::move(s2.extract(s2.begin()).value()))));
}
```

I used `std::set::extract` to successfully move an element from `std::set` to another `std::set`, as in:

```
s2.insert(std::move(s1.extract(s1.begin())));
```

But the compiler doesn't allow moving the element to `std::map` this way:

```
m1.insert(std::move(std::make_pair(1, std::move(s2.extract(s2.begin()).value()))));
```

Any help would be appreciated. [Link to compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Wf814n).

Comment: Please be more specific than “can’t”.

Comment: I am not sure whether transferring implementation-defined  node handles between different container types is the intended use case?!

Comment: @lubgr But `value()` can get the actual value of the node handle, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: You cannot do this, it's as simple as that. `extract` does not work this way.

Comment: Can you not add a move constructor?

Comment: Writing `std::move(std::make_pair(...));` doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problematic example, because MyClass is not merely non-copyable, but implicitly *non-movable* - which is probably not what you meant. (I think MyClass becomes immovable as a result of you explicitly deleting the copy constructor; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13345578/1593077).)

If you do make `MyClass` movable, like so:

```
class MyClass : NonCopyable
{
public:
    MyClass(int i) : v(i) {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    MyClass(MyClass&& other) : v(other.v) {
        std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~MyClass() {
        std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }
    bool operator<(const MyClass& r) const {
        return v < r.v;
    }

    int v;
};
```

all seems to go well, when you write, say.

```
m1.emplace(
    1,
    std::move( 
        s2.extract(s2.begin()).value() 
    )
);
```

You can see this working on [<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/j6Pejs).

---

<sub>PS - As @DavisHerring suggests, you might want to use the `try_emplace()` method instead, if you don't want to overwrite an existing value.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, you're right! In the real case of this question, `MyClass` is similar to `std::unique_ptr`. This is my test example error.

Comment: You’ve answered the literal question; I seem to have answered the title (or the spirit of the question?).  I don’t know which is more useful!

Answer (score 3):

The point of `extract` and the corresponding overload of `insert` is to manipulate node-based containers without memory **allocation**.  (One interesting such manipulation is to change `std::map` keys.)  That cannot work here because the nodes are different types (*viz.*, one has a key and the other doesn’t), so you need to just use the value with a *regular* `insert` (or the more ergonomic `try_emplace`).

Comment: Heh, interesting wording question - does a set contain keys or does a set contain values? I'd always thought of it as the former but apparently you think of it as the latter.

Comment: @JeJo Why should it not work? The fact that the value in question here comes from an `extract()` call doesn't really matter - it's just that you made `MyClass` movable (so this call can move it just fine) but in OP's case it was not (so it cannot).

Comment: @Barry: The standard calls them keys, and that’s certainly appropriate in a context where various container types are in play (*cf.* Python, where `set(my_dict)` copies the keys, since they’re what’s hashable and unique).  I think of them as values because it lets all containers have values; also, iterating over a `set` (which yields `value_type` for *any* container) is very common and there is no `operator[]` (although of course the key-like `find` can be useful for canonicalization and `count` for membership testing).

Comment: @Barry: Two more points: node handles for a `std::set` call it `value_type` only (since you can’t look anything up there, I guess), and this question happened to want to use the `set` elements as the `mapped_type` (which I would also tend to call “values” despite `std::map<…>::value_type` being the `pair`).