# How to guard move constructors for C++03 and C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, c++03

This is similar to [What differences, if any, between C++03 and C++11 can be detected at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6473218). But in this case, I want detection to occur via the preprocessor.

How should we guard the [move constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10402241) (and [move assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29#Rule_of_5)) when the sources are used in both C++03 and C++11?

Is the following sufficient (is [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3106110) something all C++ compilers adopted due to it being essential/core feature)?

```
#if (__cpluplus >= 201103L)
    Foo(Foo&& other);
#endif
```

Or do I need to get into compiler specifics? If we need compiler specific macros, then how do we handle situations like [Visual Studio 2012 __cplusplus and C++ 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14131454)?

Sorry to ask. I don't have some of these compilers to test on, like Visual Studio 2012, Intel ICC and Comeau.

---

**EDIT**: the library uses a GNUmakefile and Standard C++ 03. It does not use Autotools, it does not use Cmake, and it does not use Boost.

Comment: Use [Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) and `BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES`?

Comment: If you happen to be using CMake, check out their recently added [compile feature detection](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html).

Comment: Thanks T.C. This library does not use Boost. I updated the question to make it clear. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Move semantics is one of the core C++11 new features (it is one of the reasons for the new Standard, in some ways) and thus for any conforming compiler it should suffice with:

```
#if (__cpluplus >= 201103L)
....
#endif
```

Ditto with, say, something as "essential" as variadics and the new semantics for auto.

Of course, once you get into the land of compiler specifics, such as a broken compiler or if you want move semantics to work in compilers that provide "C++0x" or emulation mode instead of the real thing, then... well, you get into the land of compiler specifics. For a good subset of those you don't need to even adopt any external library (be it Boost, cxxomfort, etc) but simply copy and adapt the relevant macros and tests in the [Predef Wiki](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/).