# How to override integral promotion rule for enum?

Tags: c++, enums, integer-promotion

This is closely related to [Are C++ enums signed or unsigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159034). According to JavaMan's answer, an `enum` is neither `signed` nor `unsigned`. But it does follow integral promotion rules.

I'm working with a library that uses `enums` and then passes them to other class objects that expect mostly `unsigned` types (like `unsigned int` and `size_t`). Enabling the `-Wsign-conversion` warning in an effort to catch legitimate mistakes is causing a number false positives due to the language's rules.

The rule kind of creates a a situation where its difficult to ensure type safety and catch common mistakes. Its difficult because I want to avoid things like `static_cast` sprinkled liberally throughout the code.

Is there a way to override the language's default behavior for promoting `enums` to concrete `signed` or `unsigned` types? (Similar to the way you can specify a `char` is signed or unsigned).

---

Related, the library was written in the 1990s, so it supports a number of older compilers. It would be great if the solution addressed even C++03 and possibly earlier.

From [How to guard move constructors for C++03 and C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30797388), I know there's no reliable way in practice to detect when other C++ language variants are in effect. It fell flat on its face during testing with Clang 3.5 using `-std=c++03` and `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Can you use C++11, and can you modify the enum definitions in this library?

Comment: @Praetorian - Unfortunately, no, we can't depend upon C++11. We still need to support C++03 (and possibly earlier). On the good side, I can modify the enum definitions in the library. If needed, the library is Wei Dai's [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/). Sorry about not providing that information sooner.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying type of a C++03 enumeration depends on the range of values of its enumerators, and it promotes to its underlying type, not `int` (C++98 [conv.prom] §4.5/2).

The dirty way to force an enumeration to behave as `unsigned int` is to add a value that only `unsigned int` can handle.

```
enum things {
    a, b, c,
    force_unsigned = -1U
};
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3ded108fb5a68bf

Comment: had to scratch my head what the "-1u" will result in, this helped me: http://brnz.org/hbr/?p=1433

Comment: @user2950911 Yeah, and it's important that `-1u` is a positive number. All the enumerator values need to be positive for this to work, or the compiler will be forced choose `signed long` or `signed long long`, which can hold both `-1u` and proper negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own `enum class`:

```
struct safe_enum {
    enum type {
        value1, value2, value3
    };
    type value;

    operator unsigned int ()
        { return value; }
};

safe_enum foo = safe_enum::value1;
unsigned bar = safe_enum::value2;
```

Unfortunately, this loses the "unscoped" behavior of C++03 enumerations, so this best-practice pattern will break the codebase. Also, changing an `enum` into a `class` will break the ABI, if this has been shipped as a DLL.